# parse Javascript json into php

Tags: php, json

Here is my Json. This ia an dwr response ( a webservice created in java) .

```
{
  key1 : {
     date : "Today" ,
     items : [
           {
             itemKey1 : "itemValue1",
             itemKey2 : "itemValue2",
           },
             {
             itemKey1 : "itemValue1",
             itemKey2 : "itemValue2",
           },
     ]
   }
}
```

**JSON LINT is also showing the error.**

If you can see key do not have "" may be that's why i can not parse it to json in php directly. Is there any way oi can parse it to json and then to array or directly to an array.

**But when i transfor this to this type of json it. In JSON LINT it shows that it is proper json.**

```
{
"key1": {
    "date": "Today",
    "items": [
        {
            "itemKey1": "itemValue1",
            "itemKey2": "itemValue2"
        },
        {
            "itemKey1": "itemValue1",
            "itemKey2": "itemValue2"
        }
    ]
 }
}
```

**So is there anyway i can trasnfer json to second type. Dynamically in PHP**

Comment: @Gerton  via JSON LINT i get =>  Parse error on line 1:
{    key1: {        date
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'

Comment: @Uchiha It is not working ...!!! It returns nothing,....

Comment: This is not valid JSON... JSON needs to have key names wrapped in quotes.

Comment: Yeah that is my problem... Is there any way i can dynamically assign quotes to the keys ????  @EJTH

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't just serialize the data properly? Are you or your organization responsible for the java service? If so you should really change that to be JSON compliant instead of doing wierd wrangling of the data. But i suppose you COULD do some ugly regex to compensate for the missing quotes, but it WILL be flaky!

Comment: @EJTH ok then will try with that ... if there is any php way then it could be better ...!!! I have to do it server side... retrieve data and insert into database....

Comment: @EJTH i really do not want to use preg_match ... in this case ... but let me see what can i do with this...

Comment: no...you need to change your service to give valid json through response...if the json is not valid then how could you parse it..

Comment: @JaiminMosLake ... sticks to basic...on the other side..we can achieve that throught that invalid json..by using some trick..but thats not recomemded...

Comment: @AngadTiwari will keep it in mind

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no javascript parser build in to PHP and what you have here is JAVASCRIPT and not JSON, your only options is really to implement your own parser / use an existing parser. OR wrangle your string into being JSON, this COULD be done with something like regex, though it will most likely be flaky.

For your specified example data, this would do:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(preg_replace_callback('#(\S+)\s*:#i', function($matches){
  return '"'.$matches[1].'" :';
},$str));
```